# Rails 4 + Amazon S3: Grant access to Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a Rails API and would like to enable access to my Amazon S3 Bucket but when my API attempts to access a URL that points to an object in my bucket, it receives a `403 Forbidden` response.

I do not want to make the objects public, but would like to allow my API access.  I've tried to [generate a bucket policy](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) but have had no luck.

If anyone has experience with this, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an IAM Policy that enables a set of credentials to access objects inside the S3 Bucket. If you're not running your Rails application inside AWS, create a User that has this policy attached to it, with access credentials. Otherwise, if you're running on AWS, you can attach an IAM policy to a Role, which is attached to an EC2 Instance, etc.

See: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/

Comment: I've tried to create a policy using the generator but it tells me `Error: Policy has invalid action` when my only actions are:  `"s3:CreateBucket"`, `"s3:DeleteBucket"`, `"s3:DeleteObject"`, `"s3:GetBucketAcl"`, `"s3:GetObject"`, `"s3:ListAllMyBuckets"`, `"s3:ListBucket"`, `"s3:PutBucketAcl"`, `"s3:PutObject"` which all came from the generator

Comment: That's very odd, but typically you should be able to apply actions quite granularly. I've pasted an example policy, which you should be able to easily expand to include the actions you've listed.

Just remember to change the resource name, to match your bucket.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1493302798439",
      "Action": [
        "s3:CreateBucket",
        "s3:DeleteBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
```